# Cant't find unit LRessources used by component1

Tags: compiler-errors, debian, components, lazarus

I'm trying to create a component in Lazarus, I created the package, added the component but when I click to install I get this compilation error:
"Cant't find unit LRessources used by component1".
The type of my component is TComponent, My OS is Debian, I installed Lazarus using the command:
aptitude install Lazarus, 
fpc and fpc-src are autamatically installed with lazarus-IDE.
How can I fix this error? 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you add 'LCL' package to dependencies of your package? It allow the compiler to find units from LCL including `LResources`. Also check the unit name spelling.

Comment: No, I'im new to Lazarus, I'm asking you to show me how to add dependecy to a package, I took a look on "Package options" and "compiler options" in the configuration package window, but I don't know how to act.

Comment: At the top of package window (not of package options) click "Add" button and select "New Requirement".

Comment: I really don't know how to thank you, I'm so grateful, the component is created. THANKS A LOT!!